# symfony2 @security.user.entity_manager changed name or something?

Tags: symfony

Upon updating from sym2.0 to 2.3 I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]                                                   
The service "security.firewall.map.context.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.user.entity_manager".
```

Below is my firewall config:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            success_handler: security.authentication.success_handler
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

And the success handler that it refers to:

```
services:
    security.authentication.success_handler:
        class: %security.authentication.success_handler.class%
        public: false
        arguments:  ['@router', '@security.user.entity_manager']      #<------- Here
```

PS I know I'm getting the same error as this guy [issue with providers and chain_provider in symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452328/issue-with-providers-and-chain-provider-in-symfony) only his was caused by some facebook login integration, I don't have that at all so seems unrelated,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` is what the entity manager service should be in 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and realized it ocurred because the service was into a bundle that extends FosUserBundle. Try adding any other service in success_handler. If error changes, this could be the cause.